# js событие wheel скроллинг соседнего элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

имеется такая задачка.
есть div со скролом. (overflow-y:auto)
над ним с position:fixed  располaгается другой div
но ситуация такая что второй див мешает прокрутке в первом диве.
то есть хочу сделать следующее, когда курсор находится на диве с fixed позицией то при работе колесиком мыши или свайпах происходил обычный скролинг в первом диве.
есть ли такая возможность? или можно это на уровне событий както проксировать?

Comment: Просто добавьте `pointer-events: none;` для блока, который мешает прокрутке.

Comment: не совсем то. на диве c fixed есть дочерние элементы для которых обработка событий мыши нужна.  нужно чтоб не обрабатывались именно события колесика мыши

Comment: пока сделал так для дива с fixed , а все дочерние элементы которые активные с pointer-events: auto, и ловят события тачпада и колесика мыши. надеюсь это временный вариант. думаю придется свой скрол контейнер пилить чтоб отлаженно передавать из других элементов события скролинга))